Numpythonic way of float to signed integer normalization
What is the faster numpythonic way of this normalization:
def normalize_vector(x, b, axis):
    """
    Normalize real vector x and outputs an integer vector y.

    Parameters:
        x (numpy.ndarray): Input real vector. (batch_size, seq_len)
        b (int): Unsigned integer defining the scaling factor.
        axis (int/None): if None, perform flatenned version, if axis=-1, perform relative normalization across batch.

    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: Integer vector y.
    """
    # Find the maximum absolute value in x
    m = np.max(np.abs(x))

    # Process each element in x
    y = []
    for xi in x:
        if xi > 0:
            y.append(int((2**b - 1) * xi / m))
        elif xi < 0:
            y.append(int(2**b * xi / m))
        else:
            y.append(0)

    return np.array(y)

Can np.digitize make it faster?
I have similar question, but it's not about NumPy.
I'm also expecting it supports axis parameter for batch vector.

Is this not identical to np.floor(2**b * (x / m)).astype(int) or so?

If it is, I'll add an answer. I just don't have a means to test it easily right now

@MadPhysicist I tried for your answer with case x = np.array([-3.14, 0, 3.14]), it doesn't work. Returning [-128    0  128] instead of [-128    0  127] for b=7

The function you gave above gives [128 0 127]

@rehaqds Apologize, I have edited it, turns out I don't need minus sign elif xi<0

there is np.piecewise to transform data based on multiple conditions.
def normalize_vector2(x, b, axis):
    # Step 1: Find the maximum absolute value in `x`
    m = np.max(np.abs(x), axis=axis)


    y = np.piecewise(x, [x > 0, x < 0],
                     [
                         lambda xi: ((2**b - 1) * xi / m), 
                         lambda xi: (2**b * xi / m)
                     ])

    return y.astype(int)

if your paths are close then you can just simplify it with multiplies.
def normalize_vector3(x, b, axis):
    # Step 1: Find the maximum absolute value in x
    m = np.max(np.abs(x), axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    m[m==0] = 1

    y = (2**b - 1 * (x > 0)) * x / m
    return y.astype(int)

comparison:
import numpy as np
import time

def normalize_vector2(x, b):
    # Step 1: Find the maximum absolute value in `x`
    m = np.max(np.abs(x))


    y = np.piecewise(x, [x > 0, x < 0],
                     [
                         lambda xi: ((2**b - 1) * xi / m),
                         lambda xi: (2**b * xi / m)
                     ])

    return y.astype(int)

def normalize_vector3(x, b, axis):
    # Step 1: Find the maximum absolute value in x
    m = np.max(np.abs(x), axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    m[m==0] = 1

    y = (2**b - 1 * (x > 0)) * x / m
    return y.astype(int)

def normalize_vector(x, b):
    # Find the maximum absolute value in x
    m = np.max(np.abs(x))

    # Process each element in x
    y = []
    for xi in x:
        if xi > 0:
            y.append(int((2**b - 1) * xi / m))
        elif xi < 0:
            y.append(int(-2**b * xi / m))
        else:
            y.append(0)

    return np.array(y)

for elements in [10, 100, 1000, 10000]:
    iterations = int(100000 / elements)
    x = np.random.random(elements) * 256-128

    t1 = time.time()
    for i in range(iterations):
        normalize_vector(x,7)
    t2 = time.time()

    for i in range(iterations):
        normalize_vector2(x, 7)

    t3 = time.time()

    for i in range(iterations):
        normalize_vector3(x, 7, 0)
    t4 = time.time()

    print(f"{(t2-t1)/iterations:.7f}, {elements} elements python")
    print(f"{(t3-t2)/iterations:.7f}, {elements} elements numpy")
    print(f"{(t4-t3)/iterations:.7f}, {elements} elements numpy maths")

0.0000109, 10 elements python
0.0000331, 10 elements numpy
0.0000158, 10 elements numpy maths
0.0000589, 100 elements python
0.0000399, 100 elements numpy
0.0000168, 100 elements numpy maths
0.0005812, 1000 elements python
0.0000515, 1000 elements numpy
0.0000255, 1000 elements numpy maths
0.0045110, 10000 elements python
0.0003255, 10000 elements numpy
0.0001083, 10000 elements numpy maths

numpy is slower than pure python for small lists (mostly < 50 elements).

But, does it support the axis parameter? I guess, the parameter must be passed into np.max(axis=axis).

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira it could, but i added a better one for your use-case

If you like pythonic list comprehension and one-liner:
b =7 
x= [-3.14, 0, 3.14]
x2 = np.array([int((2**b - 1) * xi / np.max(np.abs(x))) if xi > 0 
               else int(2**b * xi / np.max(np.abs(x))) 
               for xi in x])


Is list comprehession part of numpythonic way?
